# Ethereum geth mainnet blocked on “Looking for peers”

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, geth-debugging

I installed Geth for setup a ethereum node on my linux server and use it on my RPC API.

The problem is, Geth is posting "Looking for peers" forever, I don't really understand why. This is not a firewall problem, port 30303 TCP and UDP is allowed and works.

[image]

Here is my geth configuration:

geth --networkid 1 --http --http.port 6666 --http.api "personal, eth, web3" --datadir /root/.ethereum --syncmode fast --cache 2048 --nodiscover

My geth version is 1.9.20.

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was fixed after setting time to use from NTP.
"timedatectl set-ntp yes" is the command used.